Is it a problem that a paver driveway covers the bottom portion of vinyl siding?
The contractor says this is fine, and that he'll seal the gap with polymeric sand. It doesn't look okay to me. He also has the grade above the poured basement floor level. The one on the right is where he wants to put it, but I think it should be lower, like the one on the left.
To fix this, he'll have to regrade the driveway, and he's already compacted it. Am I crazy to demand that he fix it so that the grade is lower than the bottom of my siding and below the level of the basement floor?



Imo your contractor is an idiot. Polymeric sand is not going to create a swimming-pool level of water protection against the siding. You will have moisture trouble if you allow him to do this.

Masonry should never bury siding. Doing so lessens siding life and results in backward water flow.
I also would not want the exterior grade above my floor level at a doorway. A heavy rain could bring a deluge into your basement.
Yes, this is wrong.

You're welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.
